# Eigenvalues of the product of real symmetric matrices, coupled oscillators.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics

I want to prove, if possible, that the eigenvalues of a product of two special real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices are real and positive. I consider:

a) a diagonal matrix $M$ with positive real numbers.

b) a symmetric matrix $K$ with positive real numbers in the diagonal, $K_{i,i}>0$, and negative real numbers elsewhere, $K_{i,j}\leq 0, \ \ j\neq i$ . Additionally, on each row, the sum of the absolute value of the out of diagonal elements is smaller or equal to the diagonal one, i.e.:

$K_{i,i}\geq\sum_{j\neq i} |K_{i,j}|$.

Here is a $3\times 3$ example:
\begin{align}
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1 \ &0 \ &0 \\
0 &m_2 \ &0 \\
0 \ &0 \ &m_3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
and:
\begin{align}
K=
\begin{bmatrix}
k_1+\kappa_1 \ &-\kappa_1 \ &0 \\
-\kappa_1 &\kappa_1+\kappa_2 \ &-\kappa_2 \\
0 \ &-\kappa_2 \ &k_3+\kappa_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
I study the eigenvalues of $Z=M^{-1}K$:

$M^{-1}K x=\omega^2 x$

I want to prove that $\omega^2\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

What I know so far is that
$Z$ is not symmetric: $(M^{-1}K)^T=K^T(M^{-1})^T=KM^{-1}$, but that the eigenvalues of $Z$ and $Z^T$ are identical.
However I could not find any other result that could help.

This problem arises in the study of $n$ coupled oscillators with $M$ the matrix containing the value of the masses, and $K$ containing the value of the springs; the coupling is accounted by the out of diagonal elements of $K$. On physical ground I expect the eigenvalue $\omega^2$ to be real and positive (real frequency of oscillations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Gershgorin circle theorem the eigenvalues of $K$ are non-negative. So, $M$ is positive definite and $K$ is positive semi-definite. I can at least show that $M ^{-1}K$ has non-negative eigenvalues. For this, note that $M^{-1}K$ is symmetric with respect to the positive definite inner product $[\cdot,\cdot] = \langle M\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. So, it has real eigenvalues and $[M^{-1}Kx,x] = \langle Kx,x\rangle\ge 0$. Hence, its eigenvalues are non-negative.

EDIT: If the diagonal dominance of $K$ is strict, then $K$ is positive definite, too, and so $M^{-1}K$ has only positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I'll take some time to digest it and see if I understand everything. On the other hand, what do you mean exactly by "strict diagonal dominance" ? Does it mean that the inequality I wrote is only $>$ and not $\geq$ ? If so it would make sense physically, because if the $\geq$ is replaced by $=$ it means that no masses is attached to a wall and so that a pure translation of all the masses is an eigenmode, with frequency $ \omega=0$ :)

Comment: Yes, by strict diagonal dominance I mean $K_{ii} > \sum_{j\neq i}|K_{ij}|$.

Comment: If you don't have strict diagonal dominance, then an eigenvalue might be zero. Examples are $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}2&1&-1\\1&2&1\\-1&1&2\end{pmatrix}$.